# Как по нажатию Button прочитать данные с EditText

Tags: java, android

Есть диалог: одна кнопка и два поля EDITTEXT. Помогите сделать так, чтобы по нажатию кнопки прочитать данные введенные в EDITTEXT и присвоить их переменны типа String?
Приведите пример.

Comment: Михаил, здесь благотворительностью не занимаются. Здесь отвечают на конкретные вопросы.

Comment: Правку сделал, скажите если ещё что-то не правильно.

Comment: [`SERVERPORT = NewPort.getText().length();`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) - ну вы понимаете, да? Вам нужен [`Integer.parseInt`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Если заменить на: SERVERPORT = Integer.parseInt(Client.this.NewPort.getText().toString());    также как и раньше приложение выбивает ошибку при нажатии кнопки button.

Comment: текст ошибки в вопрос добавьте, вместе с трассой стека

Comment: Это приложение под android, на эмуляторе Socket проверить не возможно. Проверку провожу на реальном устройстве. Программа при нажатии button закрывается, и пишет ошибка приложения.

Comment: @MixGerts, если у вас возник новый вопрос, то надо создавать (задавать) новый вопрос, а не изменять текущий. Смысл сайта не в помощи конретному программисту, а в сборе базы данных решений различных задач.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, по вашему совету создал новый вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Вешайте слушатель нажатий на кнопку.
2. В нём получите `EditText` диалога.
3. Результат вызова `EditText.getText()` присваивайте переменной типа `String`.